# Android, button, link underline

Tags: android, button, hyperlink, underline

I didn't want the link on the button would be underlined. I did it this way :

string.xml

```
  <string name="link">&lt;a href="http://web.com/web.php">mighty&#10;web&lt;/a></string>
```

activity.xml

```
  <Button
         android:id="@+id/web"
         android:layout_width="160dip"
         android:layout_height="160dip"
         android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
         android:background="@drawable/bigroundbutton"
         android:textColorLink="@android:color/white"
         android:textSize="30sp" />
```

bigroundbutton.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:shape="oval">
 <solid android:color="#3a5795" />
 <corners android:bottomRightRadius="160dip"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="160dip"  
    android:topRightRadius="160dip"
    android:topLeftRadius="160dip"/>
```

activity.java

```
    Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.web);
    Spannable s = (Spannable) Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.link));
    URLSpan[] spans = s.getSpans(0, s.length(), URLSpan.class);
    for (URLSpan span: spans) {
        int start = s.getSpanStart(span);
        int end = s.getSpanEnd(span);
        s.removeSpan(span);
        span = new URLSpanline_none(span.getURL());
        s.setSpan(span, start, end, 0);
    }
    but.setText(s);

    ......................

        private class URLSpanline_none extends URLSpan {
        public URLSpanline_none(String url) {
            super(url);
        }
        @Override public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine.
I run apk, link is not underlined. I tap it. It works. Great.
Then I close App and open it again. Link is underlined.
When I re-run apk, it's not underlined again, until I tap it.

Any ideas how to fix this? Is it considered as "visited link" after the first tap? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: try using:@android:color/transparent

Comment: Then text on the button is invisible

Comment: android:textColorLink="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: Yes, text is invisible.

Comment: How are you running it? I'm testint it in the emulator and it doesn't show the link when I tap the button. Should it show you the link when the button is clicked?

Comment: No, not when clicked, but after. Click it, then close App, then open it again. You'll see underline.

Comment: Hm ... I'm playing with it more and it works fine, no underline no matter what. Probably kind of the temporary glitch related to Android 4.1.2 , I'm testing it on.

Answer (score 0):

Any issue with handling the link yourself?

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="mighty web"
    android:tag="http://web.com/web.php"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="openUrl"/>
```

---

```
public void openUrl(View v){
    String url = v.getTag().toString();
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: 1. That won't style like a link, 2. It won't have a link click effect.